# iOS check-in fails on IIS MDM with 405 despite *.ashx handling all verbs

Tags: iis-7.5, iphone, mobile-devices

I have an IIS 7.5 server which is configured to support MDM checkin over HTTPS using a cert generated from a test CA. The CA cert is installed as a trusted CA on the iOS 5 device. In IIS Manager, I've gone into My Site->Handler Mappings and for every handler associated with *.ashx, under Request Restrictions->Verbs, I have set the radio button to "All verbs" to enable PUT support for the check-in page.

This configuration allowed me to check in yesterday but today, I'm getting 405. I've rebooted the machine since then and after that, I had to make sure the Handler Mappings were set up again.

How do I get IIS 7.5 to allow PUT requests to *.ashx URLs in a permanent way so my MDM server never tells the iOS device 405?

Comment: had the handler mappings changed, and did it work post-reboot-and-remap?

Comment: And to address the "in a permanent way" - any configuration should be permanent. It's all file-based stuff. Either applicationhost.config or web.config in the content directory sounds like it got rolled back if re-setting-it-up fixed the problem.

Comment: The mystery of why it ever worked remains unsolved. A colleague suggested I delete all traces of WebDAV. This ended up solving the problem.